# Drupal registration taking long on server but not on localhost

Tags: drupal

I'm having problems with deployment of my drupal page to live server. Most of the things works great, but registration is taking quite some time(more then 60 sec). On localhost it's done in 1-2 secs. I have no idea how to debug or optimize that. I was googling and only good think i found was that https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/20023/new-user-registration-take-long-time-more-than-60-seconds , but there isn't enough information.

Please help!

So i jsut tried performance module and found out that the problem is cousing user/register...

```
Path Last access     # accesses MB Memory (Max) MB Memory (Avg) ms (Max)    ms (Avg)    Jezik 
user/register   10.05.2013, 10:42   1   37.00   37.00   60,618.0    60,618.0    sl
```

Btw i noticed it usualy take normal time + 60sec, it's like the site pouse for 60sec and then do work...
Also everything else works just as fast as on localhost ...

Comment: If somebody want to test it it's here http://staging.bringler.com/drupal/?q=user/register

Comment: Developing Drupal sites requires the devel module for efficiency. You should really take some time in chekcing it out since it will save you so much time and pain later. Here's a quick intro: http://blip.tv/worldfallz/mini-lesson-devel-module-quickie-1145093

Comment: Yea but it all works fast on my localhost, i jsut want to know why it took so much time on live ...

Comment: @span I'm not sure where you've got that information from but it's totally incorrect; Drupal does _not_ require the Devel module for anything to with performance/efficiency. The Devel module contains helpers for _developers_ as the name suggests. If you've got that module enabled on a production site, you're doing something wrong.

Comment: So can somebody explain why i'm getting minuses? I'm stuck with that for whole day :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wow i finaly found a solution in function logintoboggan_user_register_submit i needed to comment out line

```
 //$redirect = _logintoboggan_process_redirect(variable_get('logintoboggan_redirect_on_register', ''), $account);
```

and manualy write the redirect!

Comment: Bear in mind you will lose your changes whenever anyone updates loggintoboggan, it also means that some of the configurability of the module is lost. For the sanity of anyone who may have to work on the site in future, at least document it somewhere. If you can pinpoint the exact problem, and you manage to patch it, it would be helpful to add an issue to the logintoboggan issue queue.